# Combinación de filtros

Tags: javascript, filtro, module.exports

Hola podrían ayudarme con este problema que tengo, estoy tratando de combinar los filtros, dentro de la función filter le coloque algunas condiciones con las que quiero que cumpla para que después pueda mostrarlo en la pantalla, estoy utilizando módulos

```
export function filters(data, team, medal, sport) {  
  const datas = data.filter(athlete => athlete.team === team && athlete.medal === medal && athlete.sport === sport);  
  return datas;
}
```

Esta es la otra parte

```
import data from './data/athletes/athletes.js'; 
import {filters} from './data.js'; 
const datos = data.athletes; 
const selects = document.getElementById("countries","medalSelect", "sport"); 
function mostrarData(data) {
let allcards = ""
data.forEach((athlete) => {
allcards += `<div class="card contentcard"> 
        <p class="cardName"><strong>${athlete.name.toUpperCase()}</strong></p>
        <img class="icon" src="./${athlete.medal}.png">
        <p>${athlete.medal}</p>
        <p>${athlete.team} ${athlete.noc}</p>
        <p>${athlete.event}</p>
        </div>`
    });
    document.getElementById("root").innerHTML = allcards;
}
mostrarData(datos);
selects.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
const allData = (filters(datos, e.target.value));
mostrarData(allData);
});
```

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema

Comment: Hola, Bienvenido@. Las publicaciones que no contienen una descripción de un problema y donde se ubica este en especifico, no son bien recibidas por la comunidad. Por favor, revisa [como hacer un pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y edita tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte. Gracias